# Userform Check date & time

Tags: excel, vba, userform

Hi I have a userform which looks through column A for a value usually something like 14/11/2018  17:00:01. if I actually enter a correct value my code brings up the error I have entered if you type in an incorrect value. Where have I gone wrong?

```
Private Sub TimeBox_AfterUpdate()

    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheet4.Range("A:A"), Me.TimeBox.Value) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Time not found"
        Me.TimeBox.Value = ""
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code instead of yours

```
Private Sub TimeBox_AfterUpdate()
Dim m, lr As Long
Dim cell As Range
s = Me.TimeBox.Text

lr = Sheets("Sheet4").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

   For Each cell In Sheets("Sheet4").Range("A1:A" & lr)

   If cell.Text = s Then
   m = m + 1
   End If
   Next cell

   If m = 0 Then
   MsgBox "Time not found"
   Else
   MsgBox m
   End If

End Sub
```